# how to check exist relation in eloquent query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am using the `laravel` polymorphic relation.

cartable model:

```
public function  objectable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

instructions model:

```
public function cartable()
{
    return $this->morphMany('PTA_OIMS\Cartable', 'objectable');
}
```

reports model:

```
public function reports()
{
    return $this->morphMany('PTA_OIMS\Cartable', 'objectable');
}
```

My instruction table has extra related table called instruction_logs.

But in the reports table, this relationship does not exist.
When my object is report this query has error. Because the reports.report_logs does not exist.

```
$data = Cartable::where('id', '=', $cartableID)
    ->with('objectable')
    ->with('objectable.objectable_logs.attachment') //line error
    ->with('box.position')
    ->with('box.assign.staff')
    ->first();

return $data;
```

How to handle query if objectable_logs did not exist skip the *line error*?

Comment: An `if`-statement? You can continue the chain after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = Cartable::with([
    'objectable',
    'objectable.objectable_logs.attachment',
    'box.position',
    'box.assign.staff'
])->find($cartableID);

return $data;
```

if `attachment` is a column in `objectable_logs` table, it should be like:

```
$data = Cartable::with([
    'objectable',
    'objectable.objectable_logs:objectable_id,attachment',
    'box.position',
    'box.assign.staff'
])->find($cartableID);

return $data;
```